# How can Kingo hear Sprite complaining even when she wasn't there?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, eternals-2021

In *Eternals* (2021), Sprite walks out on Kingo and Ikarus comforts him:

> Kingo: Hey. Don't sweat it. Sprite's always cranky. **I used to hear her complaining
> even when she wasn't there**.
>
> Ikarus: I'm okay, Kingo.

How can Kingo hear Sprite complaining even when she wasn't there?

Comment: Because it's so persistent and common that he hears her complaining *in his imagination*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

He's saying that she does it so often that he "hears" the complaining as a memory or imagination thereof, not that he literally hears her.